# Confusion on Softening Mask Edge in AECS6

Tags: after-effects

So I am fairly inexperienced with After Effects. But I am making a title for a video project and am having a hard time figuring something out. I have some text that slides over, and appears once it is in the masked area. However this is a very hard edge and doesn't look the best. How do I soften that edge? I tried making another shape and blurring it and then masking that over the other shape but that didn't work. I tried Googling but it was full of people saying you cannot feather a shapes edges in AE.

I would use the mask in my image directly with the feather option but then that mask moves with my image, and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I learned that you can just make an image in photoshop that does whatever you want it to do and just use that.

Answer (score 0):

The masks feathering moves your image? Can you put up a screen recording of the problem?